# Skip null check in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to write unit test cases for one of the methods in code.Below is the method

```
public boolean isValid() {
    if(object == null)
       return false
   //do something here and return value.
}
```

The object is created by this method which is done before without getter setter method.

```
private Object returnObject() {
   object =  Axis2ConfigurationContextFactory.getConfigurationContext();
   return object;
}
```

When I try to test isValid(), the object is always null, so it never goes in the code to do something.

I was checking if there is any way to skip that line or make the object not null. I also tried creating an object using returnObject method. But it uses Axis library classes which throws error if it does not find certain data. What can be done in this case? I am dealing with legacy code so any pointers would be helpful.

Edit : Adding test implementation.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "javax.management.*" })
public class ClassTest {
   private ClassTest classTestObj;

@BeforeMethod
public void callClassConstructor() {
    classTestObj = //call class constructor
}

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

@Test
public boolean isValidTest() {
   Boolean result = classTestObj.isValid();
   Assert.assertEquals(result);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show how you call your methods and how you set up your mocks.

Comment: You can not mock it without PowerMockito because it is static.
How did you mock it?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I suppose you are asking about Axis2ConfigurationContextFactory.getConfigurationContext. Yes, it is static and I am not able to mock it. What I was trying to say was that if I pass required variables to that method call it fails.

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something about mocking static methods with Mockito. You can mock static methods without PowerMockito. You can make use of MockedStatic - https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.4.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the before comment, you can make use of MockedStatic to mock the static method - https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.4.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

So your code will somewhat look like the below one if you are making use of Mockito instead of PowerMockito.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassTest
{
@Mock
private Object mockAxis2ConfigurationContextFactoryObject;

  @Test
  public boolean isValidTest() {
    try (MockedStatic<Axis2ConfigurationContextFactory> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Axis2ConfigurationContextFactory.class)) {
      mockedStatic.when(()->Axis2ConfigurationContextFactory.getConfigurationContext()).thenReturn(mockAxis2ConfigurationContextFactoryObject); 
      Boolean result = classTestObj.isValid();
      Assert.assertEquals(result); 
    }
}
```